# laravel complex sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

i have 3 tables: airlines,flights,infos.

1. every airline "has many" flight.
2. every flight "has many" infos.
3. every airline "has many through" infos.

i need query query db Or eloquent ORM to get this information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
  id  | airline_name | infos_count | infos_canceled | infos_late
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1     b_airline           6             2            5(minutes)   


airline_name: name of airline company

infos_count: count of info which belong to flight table and this airline company

infos_canceled: count of info where (status=0)

infos_canceled: sum of (subtract time of schedule_time)
```

[image: Tables diagram]

i did this using transformer class but i want this using query..
any help please..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id
     , A.name AS 'airline_name'
     , COUNT(I) AS 'infos_count'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN I.status = 'Canceled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'infos_canceled'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN I.status = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'infos_late'
  FROM airlines A
  INNER JOIN flights F
          ON A.id = f.airline_id
  INNER JOIN infos I
          ON F.id = I.flight_id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .. ( id, airlinename,infos_count ) worked by add    "GROUP BY A.id" but Canceled and Late not working

Comment: What field determines when a status is canceled or late?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Jake for your answer , my answer :

```
Airline::select([
                'airlines.id',
                'airlines.name',
                \DB::raw('count(*) as flight_count'),
                \DB::raw('CAST(SUM(i.time-i.schedule_time) AS time) as flight_late'),
                \DB::raw('count(CASE WHEN i.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) as canceled_count')
            ])
                ->join('flights as f', 'f.airline_id', '=', 'airlines.id')
                ->join('infos as i', 'i.flight_id', '=', 'f.id')
                ->groupBy('airlines.id');
```